# Creating a button image with padding bottom in Swift

Tags: swift, image, button, swift3, background

I'm creating a system of Filters.

I'm trying to do that:

[image]

Currently I'm using the setBackgroundImage func, and I don't have this little rect below the picture:

```
filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)
```

I tried functions like this one:

```
filterButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
```

But it's not effective if I keep the setBackgroundImage func.

If I use setImage(), the results is good but the click is not effective any more.

```
filterButton.setImage(imageForButton, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Do you have an idea to do what I would like ?

The full snippet:

```
 for i in 0 ..< CIFilterNames.count {
         itemCount = i

         // Button properties
         let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
         // filterButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
         filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
         filterButton.tag = itemCount
         filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.filterButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
//         filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
//         filterButton.clipsToBounds = true

         let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
         let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
         let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
         filter!.setDefaults()
         filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
         let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
         let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
         let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
         filterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
         filterButton.setImage(imageForButton, for: UIControlState.normal)
         //filterButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 15,right: 0)
         //filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)
         filterButton.setTitle("A\(i)", for: .normal)
         // filterButton.backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
         filterButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 22 / 255, green: 21 / 255, blue: 22 / 255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
         filterButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
         filterButton.titleEdgeInsets.top = 140

         // Add Buttons in the Scroll View
         xCoord +=  buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
         filtersScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)

      }
```

Comment: Is the image and the filterbutton two separate elements?
Can you share a bigger snippet of code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes it's two different elements.
I edited my question with more code (it's a function to show several buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do everything in a single UIButton. I would suggest creating a custom element to handle this.
There are a few ways you could setup a custom UI element with the functionality that you want:

1. Use a UILabel to display the "A1" label with the colored background and display the image itself in a separate UIImageView. These could be overlaid with a invisible UIButton to receive the touchUpInside event and pass to your controller.
2. Alternatively, you could create a custom UIControl add add a UILabel and UIImageView as subviews. Disabling userInteraction on the subviews should allow the UIControl to receive the touch events. This could be contained in a single reusable class as if it's one UI element.

Comment: Indeed it was so simple ... I feel stupid ... I just created second buttons with the same target ...
Thank you very much !

Comment: Awesome. That's even simpler than what I was proposing. Sometime simple is best.